# Quadrature signal with L297

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, driver, quadrature

I'm trying to generate a quadrature signal with a L297 
http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/f9/35/6e/3f/48/18/48/51/CD00000063.pdf/files/CD00000063.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000063.pdf
I use only phase A and C in order to have a 90° offset

```
Here is my wiring:
// L297 -> MCU
2 GND -> GND
4 A -> read out phase A
7 C -> read out phase C
10 ENABLE -> GPIO Pin 1
12 Vs - +5v
11 Control -> GPIO Pin 5 set to high for phases line ABCD
17 CW/CCW -> GPIO Pin 2 set to high or low depeding the direction
18 Clock -> GPIO Pin 3
19 Half/Full -> GPIO Pin 6 set to low for full step
20 RST -> +5v
```

According to my understanding, when I want the L297 to run, I write a bit on GPIO Pin 1 (HIGH) to enable the L297
For changing direction, I must put Pin 2 High or Low
And when I want to send a pulse, I write a bit on Pin 3 /Clock
i'm sending pulse to clock but channel A and C stay always low. 
Do you have any idea of what could go wrong with my wiring ? or with my understanding ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you simply setting the clock line high each step, or are you remembering to actually produce a pulse?

Comment: I set alternatively the pin HIGH then LOW then High etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have current sense R to ground, and a Vref on p15 , a floating input that exceeds Vref p15 which is also floating, it will reset the outputs.

Comment: OK I put 2v (randomly choose between 0 and 3v) on Vref.
What should I do with this part of your comment " current sense R to ground"?

Comment: 0V or a resistor to ground

Comment: but connected to what?

Comment: look at the IC schematic and you will see these pins on a comparator. It is supposed to sense motor current and shutoff when > Vref

Comment: Ok, thank you
I connected both SENS1 and 2 to ground, Vref with 2v but I have the same result, my counter is still going up very quickly and never stop. I don't know what 'im doing wrong

Comment: Follow spec and confirm every input and output